# Finding options to pass to methods in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How are you supposed to find the different options you can pass to methods in Rails? For instance I want to know the options I can pass to `validates`. I can't find them nowhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

api dock is useful and it also shows the source code http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates

Answer (score 0):

As you know it's not possible to document hash options in the signature so you must either rely on the quality of the documentation or read the source code.

In this case the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates) show some examples that cover pretty much all the default validators. Note that it cannot document all the available since they can be expanded dinamically.

```
>> ActiveModel::EachValidator.descendants
=> [Paperclip::Validators::AttachmentSizeValidator, ActiveModel::Validations::WithValidator, ActiveModel::Validations::ExclusionValidator, ActiveRecord::Validations::AssociatedValidator, ActiveModel::Validations::ConfirmationValidator, ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator, ActiveModel::Validations::FormatValidator, Paperclip::Validators::AttachmentContentTypeValidator, Paperclip::Validators::AttachmentPresenceValidator, ActiveRecord::Validations::UniquenessValidator, ActiveModel::BlockValidator, ActiveModel::Validations::NumericalityValidator, ActiveModel::Validations::AcceptanceValidator, ActiveModel::Validations::InclusionValidator, ActiveModel::Validations::LengthValidator]
```

Or:

```
ActiveModel::EachValidator.descendants.map { |klass| klass.name.split("::").last.sub(/Validator$/, '').underscore }
 => ["attachment_size", "with", "exclusion", "associated", "confirmation", "presence", "format", "attachment_content_type", "attachment_presence", "uniqueness", "block", "numericality", "acceptance", "inclusion", "length"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The starting point is always the official Rails documentation. For instance, here's the documentation of the [`validates`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates) method.

However, keep in mind that Rails is a constantly evolving framework. Unfortunately, this means that not all methods are fully documented and sometimes you need to dig into the source code directly to understand how a method works.